Mail Merge Data Source References Prior Directory
using some resources I found on here I'm trying to setup an automated mail merge. This worked when I first tried it, but the following day it began to ask for a table reference, when previously it would just open the data source.

The issue seems to be that the data source being used is incorrect. For example, the macro is looking for a data source in file path S:\abc\def but the string I gave it is S:\abc\def\ghi\file.xlsx. The filepath shouldn't be long enough to cause any issues.
Dim wdApp As Object, wdDoc As Object
Dim strWorkbookName As String: strWorkbookName = ThisWorkbook.FullName

Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

With wdApp
  .Visible = True
  .WordBasic.DisableAutoMacros
  .DisplayAlerts = 0 ' wdAlertsNone
  Set wdDoc = .Documents.Open(Filename:=standard_path & "\Admin\file.doc", _
    ConfirmConversions:=False, ReadOnly:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
  With wdDoc
    With .MailMerge
      .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
      .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
      .SuppressBlankLines = True
      .OpenDataSource Name:=strWorkbookName, ReadOnly:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
        LinkToSource:=False, Connection:="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;& User ID=" & Environ("UserName") _
            & ";Data Source=strWorkbookName;;Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";", _
        SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Sheet1$`", SubType:=wdMergeSubTypeAccess
      With .DataSource
        .FirstRecord = wdDefaultFirstRecord
        .LastRecord = wdDefaultLastRecord
      End With
      .Execute Pause:=False
    End With
    .Close SaveChanges:=False
  End With
End With

I've tried taking the code and putting it in a new workbook, no luck. I have debug.printed the workbook name and the filepath is correct. I've tried using the filepath + wkbk name instead of "thisworkbook.fullname" as well, no luck. Very confused because this worked previously.
EDIT: Thank you for the help, can't believe I messed up the quotes. I do have a new issue now that it's not getting stuck there anymore, I've updated the code a bit below.
.OpenDataSource Name:=strWorkbookName, ReadOnly:=True, _
            LinkToSource:=False, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
            Connection:="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
            "User ID=" & Environ("UserName") & ";Data Source=" & strWorkbookName & ";" & _
            "Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";", _
            SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Sheet" & s & "$`", SubType:=wdMergeSubTypeAccess

Few things:
-s is the sheet number. I'm having this run for 3 different mail merges, there are multiple sheets that it needs to reference in order to do so.
-strWorkbookName is the name of the excel workbook it's referencing
I'm now being prompted to "open data source" once it reaches the above code. Any idea what would prompt this? Having trouble finding a similar issue online. Once I select excel, it says that word is unable to open the data source.

Where is standard_path coming from?

You're passing in the literal value strWorkbookName for the path?  Should be more like & ";Data Source=" & strWorkbookName & ";Mode=Read;....

@TimWilliams thanks Tim, can't believe I missed that! I added some additional comments in my post for a new error I'm getting, would you mind taking a look if you get a chance? Still looking into it, so if I find out the solution I'll add it at the bottom.

Is strWorkbookName the full path to the source workbook, or just its name?

Hi @TimWilliams , it's the full path to the workbook, including the .xlsx. It's back to asking me to select a table now.

.OpenDataSource Name:=strWorkbookName  you could try using just the file name here.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.mailmerge.opendatasource has "Name Required String The data source file name. You can specify a Microsoft Query (.qry) file instead of specifying a data source, a connection string, and a query string."  Or see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62011584/478884 where the OP concluded they needed to use a separate workbook as the data source.

When you see that dialog box, it means that Word is trying to connect to the Excel file using ODBC. Word usually tries OLE DB first. If it presents the ODBC dialog, it's a fallback that tells you there's something it doesn't like either about the OpenDataSource parameters (most likely the SQLStatement) or the Excel file itself - e.g. it is password protected. In OpenDataSource, I would just use the Name parameter (use the full path+file name and the SQLStatement (and SQLStatement1 if you happen to need a longer piece of SQL).

In this case, my guess is that the OLE DB provider can't find the sheet name (does the "s" variable contain what you think? - perhaps it's 0 or ""?). Word + ODBC is now a bad mix for Excel data sources - it may function with an old .xls, but then you have to click Options... in the dialog and check all the boxes before you see and sheet names/named ranges. Not sure it works at all with .xlsx.
